# Thread pool worker implementation

Tags: c++, c++11, thread-safety, reinventing-the-wheel

As an exercise in using C++11 features I decided to make a thread pool class.

I would like to have a review on the code with focus on:

- Standards compliance / Portability issues / Best practices
- Thread Safety / Exception handling
- API
- Performance issues (Yes I know `std::mutex` is slow on windows, but besides that :)
- Any ideas on how I can get rid of the specialization on `void` return type?

I have inlined all methods in the class declaration to make it easier to read here. In the actual implementation they are not inlined. Sorry for the failed line-breaks on some places, the CR code window is a bit narrower than I'd like.

```
#include <functional>
#include <future>
#include <deque>
#include <thread>

/// <summary> A typical thread worker queue that can execute arbitrary jobs. 
/// </summary>
///
/// <remarks>
///  * Thread Safety   : Full.
///  * Exception Safety: Strong. </remarks>
class WorkQueue{
public:
    /// <summary> Constructors a new work queue object. </summary>
    /// <param name="numWorkers"> (Optional) number of workers, less than 0 to 
    ///     auto-detect (may fail on esoteric platforms). </param>
    explicit WorkQueue(int numWorkers = -1){
        if (numWorkers < 1){
            numWorkers = std::thread::hardware_concurrency() + 1;
        }
        while (numWorkers--){
            m_workers.emplace_back(std::thread(&WorkQueue::doWork, this));
        }
    }

    /// <summary> Will abort all pending jobs and run any in-progress jobs to 
    ///     completion upon destruction. </summary>
    ~WorkQueue(){
        abort();
    }

    /// <summary> Stops work queue and finishes jobs currently being executed.
    ///     Queued jobs that have not begun execution will have their promises 
    ///     broken. </summary>
    void abort(){
        m_exit = true;
        m_finish_work = false;
        m_signal.notify_all();
        joinAll();

        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(m_mutex);
            m_work.clear();
        }
    }

    /// <summary> Stops new work from being submitted to this work queue.</summary>
    void stop(){
        m_exit = true;
        m_finish_work = true;
        m_signal.notify_all();
    }

    /// <summary> Wait for completion of all submitted work. No more work will 
    ///     be allowed to be submitted. </summary>
    void waitForCompletion(){
        stop();
        joinAll();
        assert(m_work.empty());
    }

    /// <summary> Executes the given function asynchronously. </summary>
    /// <exception cref="std::runtime_error"> Thrown if attempting to submit a job
    ///     to a work queue that is terminating. </exception>
    /// <param name="function"> [in] The function to execute. </param>
    /// <returns> A std::future<RETVAL> for the result that will be generated by 
    ///     the function argument. Exceptions from the function will be 
    ///     thrown by get() on the future.</returns>
    template<typename RETVAL>
    std::future<RETVAL> submit(std::function<RETVAL()>&& function){
        if (m_exit){
            throw std::runtime_error("Caught work submission to work queue that is desisting.");
        }

        // Workaround for lack of lambda move capture
        typedef std::pair<std::promise<RETVAL>, std::function<RETVAL()>> pair_t;
        std::shared_ptr<pair_t> data = std::make_shared<pair_t>(std::promise<RETVAL>(), std::move(function));

        std::future<RETVAL> future = data->first.get_future();

        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(m_mutex);
            m_work.emplace_back([data](){
                try{
                    data->first.set_value(data->second());
                }
                catch (...){
                    data->first.set_exception(std::current_exception());
                }
            });
        }
        m_signal.notify_one();
        return std::move(future);
    }

    template<>
    std::future<void> submit(std::function<void()>&& function){
        if (m_exit){
            throw std::runtime_error("Caught work submission to work queue that is desisting.");
        }
        // Workaround for lack of lambda move capture
        typedef std::pair<std::promise<void>, std::function<void()>> pair_t;
        std::shared_ptr<pair_t> data = std::make_shared<pair_t>(std::promise<void>(), std::move(function));

        std::future<void> future = data->first.get_future();

        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(m_mutex);
            m_work.emplace_back([data](){
                try{
                    data->second();
                    data->first.set_value();
                }
                catch (...){
                    data->first.set_exception(std::current_exception());
                }
            });
        }
        m_signal.notify_one();

        return std::move(future);
    }

private:
    std::deque<std::function<void()>> m_work;
    std::mutex m_mutex;
    std::condition_variable m_signal;
    std::atomic<bool> m_exit{ false };
    std::atomic<bool> m_finish_work{ true };
    std::vector<std::thread> m_workers;

    void doWork(){
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ul(m_mutex);
        while (!m_exit || (m_finish_work && !m_work.empty())){
            if (!m_work.empty()){
                std::function<void()> work(std::move(m_work.front()));
                m_work.pop_front();
                ul.unlock();
                work();
                ul.lock();
            }
            else{
                m_signal.wait(ul);
            }
        }
    }

    void joinAll(){
        for (auto& thread : m_workers){
            thread.join();
        }
        m_workers.clear();
    }

    void operator=(const WorkQueue&) = delete;
    WorkQueue(const WorkQueue&) = delete;
};
```

Example use:

```
int main(){
    WorkQueue wq;
    wq.submit<void>([](){std::cout << "foo" << std::endl; });
    wq.submit<void>([](){std::cout << "bar" << std::endl; });
    std::future<int> f0 = wq.submit<int>([](){return 4; });
    std::future<int> f1 = wq.submit<int>([](){return 40; });

    std::cout << f1.get() << std::endl;
    wq.waitForCompletion();
    std::cout << f.get() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Please note that the code should be presented in the same way that you use it to avoid spurious errors. Compiling your code as is, gave me an error on the specialization of `submit`.

### Naming

- `pair_t` is a rather generic name that does not tell what is stored
- `m_work` could be improved a little although I don't have any idea yet
- `m_mutex` should be renamed to `m_work_mutex` to indicate what it is for (or bundle it together with `m_work` to make it impossible to access `m_work` without locking `m_mutex`)
- `m_signal` could take at least some explanation about its uses: what does it signal? Maybe the name can reflect this as well.
- `m_exit` should be named something like `m_accept_no_more_work` (or `accept_more_work` and its logic should be inverted because negation in a (boolean) variable name makes reasoning harder)
- `m_workers` could be name `m_worker_threads`

### Derive the return type automatically

Why bother the user with giving the return type to `submit` when it can be extracted?

```
template <typename FunctionObject>
auto submit(FunctionObject &&function) -> std::future<decltype(function())>;
```

### Remove code duplication in `submit`

Your two `submit` functions have largely the same code which indicates that your switch on the template parameter is too coarse. The only differing part is in the `try{}` block. The obvious solution is to extract the differing parts into an own function. For shortness I will use a template function specialization:

```
template <>
inline void WorkQueue::execute_and_set_data<void>(const DataPointer<void> &data) {
    data->second();
    data->first.set_value();
}

template <typename ReturnType>
void WorkQueue::execute_and_set_data(const DataPointer<ReturnType> &data) {
    data->first.set_value(data->second());
}
```

These functions use some template types:

```
template <typename ReturnType>
using PromiseFunctionPair =
    std::pair<std::promise<ReturnType>, std::function<ReturnType()>>;

template <typename ReturnType>
using DataPointer = std::shared_ptr<PromiseFunctionPair<ReturnType>>;
```

And they replace the call in the try catch block. Because of the nontrivial dependency between `ReturnType` and these types they cannot be used for automatic template parameter deduction:

```
try {
    execute_and_set_data<ReturnType>(data);
}
```

However, I would recommend to replace `PromiseFunctionPair` by a templated `struct` with better names for the members than `first` and `second` which would then allow automatic template parameter deduction.

### Missing includes

- you are using `std::vector` without `#include <vector>`
- you are using `assert` without `#include <cassert>`

### Typo

- `f.get()` should probably be `f0.get()`?

Besides the mentioned flaws I really enjoyed reading your code :)

Comment: Excellent review! Thanks! By the way what compiler did you use? The submit method compiles as is on VS2013. As for the include, my default PCH must have included vector and it was in the test program. The `f.get()` was a typo yes, I added that as an extra example after the fact. I thought I wouldn't mess up such a simple addition... figures lol. I will wait a bit longer with accepting an answer to see if there are more comments.

Comment: I used both gcc 4.9 and clang++3.6 the latter gave the error `error: explicit specialization of 'submit' in class scope` have a look at [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3052604/760746) for the standard's position on this problem. As to the PCH comment: I have run into this problem several times. This problem can also occur when you use your headers only in source files where the required headers are included as well. It helps to have a dummy source file for the header that does not include anything else (and no PCH) to detect missing includes.

Answer (score 9):

Let me start by saying that this is a nicely written class with good documentation. I also think that [Nobody's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/60387/26190) provides some good advice, so mostly I'll build on that.

I only have one correctness comment: you have problematic behavior in `joinAll`. If `waitForCompletion` and/or `abort` are called from multiple threads (and I can certainly imagine one thread calling `waitForCompletion` and another thread later calling `abort`), you have a race in `joinAll`; one thread may be mid-iteration when the other calls `m_workers.clear()`. Try the following:

```
void joinAll(){
    std::vector<std::thread> workers;
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(m_mutex);
        workers = std::move(m_workers);
    }
    for (auto& thread : workers) {
        thread.join();
    }
}
```

(This is only a partial solution; you'll have to add a condition variable or similar to make sure that future calls to `joinAll` don't return before this one joins all its threads).

You document `WorkQueue::WorkQueue`, saying that `numWorkers < 0` causes autodetection, but you autodetect whenever `numWorkers < 1`. That is, your documentation and implementation differ on behavior when `numWorkers == 0`.

Why, when autodetecting, do you create one more thread than the number of concurrent threads the hardware supports? Is this just to avoid special-casing the potential return of `0`?

I suggest reserving space for `m_workers`: `m_workers.reserve(numWorkers);`. It's quite minor in this case but a good habit.

When initializing `m_workers`, you use `m_workers.emplace_back(std::thread(...))`. I would either use `m_workers.emplace_back(...)` or `m_workers.push_back(std::thread(...))` (and I would prefer the first). `emplace_back` takes constructor arguments for the element type, and `push_back` has an rvalue-reference overload.

In `stop`, I would avoid setting `m_finish_work`; if `abort` has already been called, I don't think you want to override that setting, and if it hasn't, `m_finish_work` is already true.

I certainly agree with Nobody's advice to (a) extract `execute_and_set_data` and (b) make submit a template parameterized by the type of `function` rather than coercing it to `std::function<T()>`. I also agree you should introduce a `struct` with named fields rather than using `std::pair`.

`submit` should return `future`, *not* `std::move(future)`. Returning a local variable from a function already moves it, and explicitly calling `std::move` inhibits [NRVO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization). Alternatively, return `data->first.get_future()`; you never refer to `future` outside of its definition and the return line (maybe this is an artifact from an earlier version of the code in which you moved the `promise` away?).

I'd like to see a little more use of `auto`. `auto` can make code easier to read and modify by reducing the clutter of redundant code. Examples:

- `std::shared_ptr<pair_t> data = std::make_shared<pair_t>(...);` You're writing the type twice within a few characters. `std::make_shared<T>` is a well-known function that always returns `std::shared_ptr<T>`; when you specify the type of the variable you're storing it in, you're forcing me to spend brainpower making sure the variable's type makes sense (Is it the same? Is it maybe a base class pointer?).
- `std::future<T> future = data->first.get_future();` This is preventing you from templating on the function type rather than on the return type, making your code a bit less generic.
- `std::function<void()> work(std::move(m_work.front()));` There's a lot going on here; I think it reads a lot better as `auto work = std::move(m_work.front());`

The only point that I disagree with Nobody is on some of the naming comments. `m_work`, `m_mutex`, and `m_workers` all seem like fine names. However, I would certainly add comments to `m_work` and `m_workers` indicating that they should only be read or written when holding `m_mutex`'s lock and to `m_signal` indicating that it should only be signaled or waited on when holding `m_mutex`'s lock.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! Locking `m_mutex` in `joinAll` will create a dead-lock as the threads try to reacquire the mutex. I would need another mutex for `m_threads` for that. The documentation for the constructor is out of date, I caught that soon afterwards :3 It is a general rule of thumb to have `numcpu+1` worker threads for high utilization of CPU resources. The +1 is so that there is work to be executed on the CPU while one other thread is blocking on IO. But not +n>1 to avoid frequent thread context switching. That and it does nicely dodge the potential return of 0 ;)

Comment: Oops, you're right about the deadlock; I've edited to remove that advice and suggest an alternative.

Comment: An alternative to the `joinAll` I've suggested is simply to add a second `std::mutex` to the class to protect `m_workers`.

Comment: std::move leaves the vector in an unspecified, destructible state. More specifically std::move is not required to make it so that (`empty()` returns true) on the moved container which could cause problems for other threads entering the function. A better solution would be to use `workers.swap(m_workers)`. Regardless, this solution to `joinAll` changes semantics of the function to no longer block until all threads are joined (only the first entry will block). I believe the second mutex is the only choice to preserve semantics.

Comment: @EmilyL. You're right, that will break the assertion, but I don't think that otherwise your class's semantics require that the vector be empty.

Comment: You lost me there. Your solution can cause double joins as `std::move` is not required to alter the state of the moved object. Even if this is solved by using `swap` instead, the proposed `joinAll` could in a race condition wrongly return before all therads are joined. Imagine this: Thread1 calls `waitForCompletion()` and blocks on a long running job. Thread 2 calls `waitForCompletion()` but now the `m_workers` vector is empty and `joinAll()` will return. Thus `waitForCompletion()` will have returned before all jobs are complete.

Comment: @EmilyL. I was only referring to the `move` comment. The standard specifies that a moved-from thread no longer represents a thread of execution, so no double-join occurs. `std::vector::operator=(std::vector&&)` is also constant-time when the allocators compare equal, so in fact `m_workers` will no longer contain any objects. In any case, using `swap` makes this clear without having to know these corners of the standard and so is better. As for the blocking problem, this is acknowledged in the answer (which suggests a condition variable).

Comment: All of this is simply a thought exercise, as I believe adding a second mutex will produce far more readable code.