# Queue for distributing tasks between threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, concurrency, c++14

I implemented the following class to dispatch `std::function<void(void)>` objects to a thread pool. Multiple threads will block on the pop call until a task is available.

I am using the C++14 standard.

```
#pragma once

#include<memory>
#include<queue>
#include<mutex>
#include<condition_variable>

namespace alpha {

    template<typename T>
    class AsyncQueue {
        private:
            std::shared_ptr<std::queue<T>> queue;
            std::shared_ptr<std::mutex> mutex;
            std::shared_ptr<std::condition_variable> cond;

        public:
            /* Big 5 */
            AsyncQueue(const AsyncQueue& other) = default;
            AsyncQueue(AsyncQueue&& other) = default;
            AsyncQueue& operator=(const AsyncQueue& other) = default;
            AsyncQueue& operator=(AsyncQueue&& other) = default;
            virtual ~AsyncQueue() = default;

            /**
             * @brief Default constructor
             */
            AsyncQueue() :
                queue(new std::queue<T>()),
                mutex(new std::mutex),
                cond(new std::condition_variable()) {
            }

            /**
             * @brief Push a value to the async queue
             */
            void push(const T& object) {
                {
                    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(*mutex);
                    queue->push(object);
                }
                cond->notify_one();
            }

            /**
             * @brief Push a value to the async queue (move variant)
             */
            void push(T&& object) {
                {
                    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(*mutex);
                    queue->push(object);
                }
                cond->notify_one();
            }

            /**
             * @brief Pop a value from the queue
             */
            T&& pop() {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(*mutex);
                while(queue->empty()) {
                    cond->wait(lock);
                }
                T object = std::move(queue->front());
                queue->pop();
                return std::move(object);
            }
    };
}
```

Specific questions:

- Is there a way to keep both implementations of `push` DRY? The only difference is the type of the argument.
- Is this safe? I tested it multiple times with `true; while [[ $? == 0 ]]; do ./test; done`, but i'd feel a lot better if someone told me that my idea of thread-safety is correct.
- pop returns a rvalue-reference, which seems to cause problems when passing it directly to a function with the argument type `const T&`. Assigning it to a local variable first solves that, but is there a way to make push return a rvalue-reference only when it is needed? I am asking because i know C++ compilers implicitly move a lot.

**EDIT**:
The version that has the suggestions included can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/Richard-W/cfd3b8875976c371df01). I applied the BSD 3-clause license to it.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Nice first post, I hope you enjoy the ride!

Comment: The only reason to have a `virtual` destructor is inheritance. Do other classes inherit publicly from `AsyncQueue`? If not, then don't give it a virtual destrutor and possibly also mark the class as [`final`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Separation of concerns

You have the members of your class as `shared_ptr`s this indicates that you want shallow copy assignment and construction. This is not something that you should concern yourself when designing the class.

I would recommend that you design your queue as non-copyable and non-assignable. Because assigning a queue makes no sense. If the user needs to pass a queue around, it is their responsibility to make a `shared_ptr<AsyncQueue>`. This has the benefit of making your implementation cleaner, but also performing better as your member variables will now get a better cache locality.

## The big 5

Following the above the big 5 should now be:

```
        AsyncQueue(const AsyncQueue& other) = delete;
        AsyncQueue(AsyncQueue&& other) = delete;
        AsyncQueue& operator=(const AsyncQueue& other) = delete;
        AsyncQueue& operator=(AsyncQueue&& other) = delete;
        virtual ~AsyncQueue() = default;
```

(note `delete` instead of `default`). The move assignment and construction cannot be implemented as moving a mutex is not supported (for good reason).

## Use `make_shared`

If you still insist on using `shared_ptr`, you should use `make_shared` to construct them because this will co-allocate the reference count with the object data. This saves some memory but more importantly it improves data locality.

## Forwarding references

You're better off using forwarding references (also known as [universal reference](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) but forwarding reference [is the new preferred name](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4164.pdf)) for the `push` method. In fact I would go as far as to not provide `push` but instead provide `emplace` that constructs the object in place like this:

```
template<typename... Args>
void emplace(Args&&... args){
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(*mutex);
        queue->emplace(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
    cond->notify_one();
}
```

`emplace()` will construct the queued object in place using the arguments passed to `emplace()` as constructor arguments to avoid a copy. This way you leave the decision whether or not to move to your user.

```
Obj o;
asyncqueue.emplace(o); // Will copy construct.
asyncqueue.emplace(std::move(o)); // Will move construct.

// Will evaluate o*3 into a temporary and move from it. 
// Possibly eliding the copy.
asyncqueue.emplace( o * 3); 
asyncqueue.emplace("whatevz"); // Will call constructor taking c-string.
```

## Returning by move in `pop`

The reason you're crashing is that the local value you moved out of is destroyed when you leave the function scope. So you're moving from rubbish. [Returning by r-value reference: Just don't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116641/is-returning-by-rvalue-reference-more-efficient). The compiler will likely perform [(N)RVO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) and the copy will be optimized out if it is possible.

## Condtional wait

You have an infinite conditional wait. It may be useful to have a functionality to "sever" the queue and release all threads waiting on jobs.

Typically you would have:

```
std::atomic<bool> still_running{true};

void stop(){ still_running = false; cond->notify_all();}

void push(T&&){
   if(!still_running) throw error("severed pipe");
   ...
}

void pop(){
   ...
   while(queue->empty() && still_running) {
       cond->wait(lock);
   }
   if(queue->empty(){
       // Check for queue empty here, as still_running could
       // have been changed after we returned but we could still
       // return useful data.
       throw error("severed pipe");
   }
   ...
}
```

Also prefer the more concise way of waiting on a condition variable:

```
while(queue->empty()) {
    cond->wait(lock);
}
```

could be:

```
cond->wait(lock, [this](){ return !queue->empty();});
```

*For reference, you might be interested in: [my implementation of a similar class](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/60363/thread-pool-worker-implementation)*

Comment: "The following is not a function that will bind to a r-value reference" — Wrong; `T&&` here is *not* a universal (read: forwarding) reference. `T&&` is a non-const rvalue reference to `T`, which is a very specific type in this context — it's the type that `AsyncQueue<T>` was instantiated with. For example, `AsyncQueue<int>::push(int&&)`. A forwarding reference would only exist here if `T` were a completely new template type parameter subject to type deduction.

Comment: Looks good to me now! FYI, I (and `wc`) disagree with you about which version of the `cond.wait` code is "more concise". ;)

Comment: @Quuxplusone I prefer not to write explicit loops when I can, no particular reson I just think that if my logic can be expressed using a standard algorithm, it's better that way. For example I prefer to use `std::copy` over a raw loop to copy an array to another.

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a way to keep both implementations of push DRY? The only difference is the type of the argument.

I actually think you don't need the `void push(const T& object)`, a universal reference should bind to a const value. You should use `std::forward` to get the move semantics though, otherwise you copy on `queue->push(object)`

```
       /**
         * @brief Push a value to the async queue (move variant)
         */
        void push(T&& object) {
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(*mutex);
                queue->push(std::forward<T>(object));
            }
            cond->notify_one();
        }
```

---

> Is this safe? I tested it multiple times with true; while [[ $? == 0 ]]; do ./test; done, but i'd feel a lot better if someone told me that my idea of thread-safety is correct.

Seems safe for pushing/poping but it could leak while construction.

```
        std::shared_ptr<std::queue<T>> queue;
        std::shared_ptr<std::mutex> mutex;
        std::shared_ptr<std::condition_variable> cond;
```

Do you really need ptr's? I don't see a reason for them. If you really need them use `std::make_shared`

```
        AsyncQueue() :
            queue(std::make_shared<std::queue<T>>()),
            mutex(std::make_shared<std::mutex>()),
            cond(std::make_shared<std::condition_variable>()) {
        }
```

---

> pop returns a rvalue-reference, which seems to cause problems when passing it directly to a function with the argument type const T&. Assigning it to a local variable first solves that, but is there a way to make push return a rvalue-reference only when it is needed? I am asking because i know C++ compilers implicitly move a lot.

Thats because you can't return a dangling reference to a (to be cleaned-up) local variable. You should just return `T` to get the move-out behavior. Also, you don't need to cast the variable to a rvalue `std::move(object)` because a rule called '(named) return value optimization' should move it out anyways, or, if possible, creates the variable directly in-place. Your std::move prevents NRVO and RVO.

---

```
        AsyncQueue(const AsyncQueue& other) = default;
        AsyncQueue(AsyncQueue&& other) = default;
        AsyncQueue& operator=(const AsyncQueue& other) = default;
        AsyncQueue& operator=(AsyncQueue&& other) = default;
        virtual ~AsyncQueue() = default;
```

Oh, now i see why you use shared_ptr's. But thats not a good idea in my opinion. Rather than sharing the state state between copies of this class use a `shared_ptr<AsyncQueue>` and pass that around

Comment: I needed to make push a template for this to work (`template<typename U> void push(U&& object)`). When i used T&& it did not compile (`cannot bind lvalue to rvalue reference`). With a template it works. Thank you for your review.

Comment: "a universal reference should bind to a const value" — Correct; but `T&&` here is *not* a universal (read: forwarding) reference. `T&&` is a non-const rvalue reference to `T`, which is a very specific type in this context — it's the type that `AsyncQueue<T>` was instantiated with. For example, `AsyncQueue<int>::push(int&&)`. A forwarding reference would only exist here if `T` were a completely new template type parameter subject to type deduction. (As the OP has already noticed in the comment above.)